# Why "Lan" for Kan Extension?

Tags: category-theory, notation, kan-extensions

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a cocomplete category and $f: I \to J$ be a functor between small categories. Typically, the *left Kan extension along $f$* is denoted by $\operatorname{Lan}(f) : \operatorname{Fun}(C, I) \to \operatorname{Fun}(C, J)$. Dually, the right Kan extension is typically denoted by $\operatorname{Ran}(f)$.

Does anyone know what $\operatorname{Lan}$ stands for? "L" (resp. "R") probably stands for "left" (resp. "right") and maybe "a" somehow stands for "adjoint"?

Comment: I think Lan is just a weird abbreviation of "Left Kan" (similarly for right)

Comment: @AlvinJin Ohh, that would actually make a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: Similarly, there are left and right [Kan lifts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+lift), which are denoted "Lift" and "Rift" respectively.